# Cordova- jQuery and CSS code not displaying correctly

Tags: jquery, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I have asked this on the original VS with Cordova article [here](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/get-started-first-mobile-app/). But then noticed there was a Stack Overflow tag too.

I have installed jQuery Mobile 1.4.5 and Jquery 2.1.0 through NuGet and have followed this tutorial step by step for VS2015 Community, but the content is not fully showing (the whole ul) is missing and the other elements are not connecting to the CSS/jQuery for some reason. I don't think there are any JavaScript errors and no real HTML/CSS errors. I have attached image to demonstrate my issue.

Currently my work is looking like the image attached. But it should be like the image in the article.

There are no buildtime/run time error messages or warnings. 
Within the JS console, I see messages appearing.

The messages are stuff like: 'Initialization Finished (Make it so.)' , 'Setting the user agent server side failed', 'Navigation Occurred' and 'Current Window'.

Thanks.

[image: MyImage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now it works thankfully.
I had jQuery 2.1.0 installed with jQuery Mobile 1.4.5 (which I thought were compatible). I then installed jQuery 2.2.3 after which it now works, and all the weather details come up as it should.

This is weird because in the tutorial code, it shows as 2.1.0 and I thought the jQuery mobile would be compatible with it.